# Read USB Input on Android from IR sensor

Tags: usb, android

A mainstream IR sensor has 3 pinouts:

1. V*cc*: 5V power
2. GND: Reference ground
3. V*o*: Analog/Digital voltage output

One can power the sensor using phone's mini USB's V*bus* and GND (Can one?). Can one then use USB's D- and D+ pins to read the voltage from the V*o* pin?

Comment: You may have better luck using the microphone port to receiver IR.

Answer (score 3):

No. USB uses *complex* digital signaling on those data lines, that requires some digital processing power to work at all.

Using an USB enabled microcontroller to translate the output of the sensor would be one of the simplest solutions, but it needs its own program.